# Autofill Input Box Error VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to get an automatic fill in of a text box that was created using html, and input box. This is what I have:

```
Imports System.Object
Imports System.Web.UI.Control
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText

Public Class Route
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("Username") IsNot Nothing Then
        Label1.Text = "Welcome, " & Session("Username").ToString()
    Else
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
    End If

    'filling the text box
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim Hometown1 As String = ""
    Dim State1 As String = ""

    Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=CISWEB\UMCISSQL2008;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1")

    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand

    Dim sqlTable As New DataTable

    sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE UMaryEmail = " & Session("Username")

    Dim Adapter As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sqlCmd.ToString, sqlConn.ToString)

    sqlConn.Open()

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Adapter.Fill(sqlTable)

    If sqlTable.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        For intCount = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1

            Hometown1 = Convert.ToString(sqlTable.Rows(intCount)("Hometown1"))
            State1 = Convert.ToString(sqlTable.Rows(intCount)("State1"))

            intCount += 1
        Next

    Else
        intCount = 0
        Hometown1 = Convert.ToString(sqlTable.Rows(intCount)("Hometown1"))
        State1 = Convert.ToString(sqlTable.Rows(intCount)("State1"))

    End If


    sqlConn.Close()

    Request.Form("hometown") = (Hometown1 & ", " & State1)



End Sub

End Class
```

The issue is that I am getting an error every time a user signs in with the correct credentials. It is:

> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]

This error is always appearing next to the Adapter declaration

Comment: check your connection string

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: @NagarajS The same connection string is used other places in the program and is working fine.

Comment: @Dan-o The Adapter Declaration is throwing the exception.

Comment: @NagarajS Care to tell me what is wrong with my connection string?

Comment: @4EVRapkoch usually this error happens if the connection string is wrong

Comment: @NagaraS But what is WRONG with my connection string?